# BigQuery - UDF returns LEFT JOIN error when used in view

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I`m facing the following issue with BQ and UDF (when UDF is used in a view) when calculating the number of days between inputs.

```
CREATE FUNCTION my_test_function(from_date TIMESTAMP, to_date TIMESTAMP) AS (
    (
        SELECT COUNT(date) AS count FROM my_test_table                
        WHERE date >= CAST(from_date as date) and date < CAST(to_date as date)
    )
);
```

```
my_test_table - one column - date as DATE
```

When invoking the function in the query editor, it all works fine.

When using it in view, I got the following error.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.
```

Looking at the execution plan - there are no JOINs there. Just INPUT and OUTPUT.

**INPUT**

```
READ    
$1:date
FROM my_test_table
WHERE and(greater_or_equal($1, 18748), less($1, 18778))
AGGREGATE   
$20 := COUNT($1)
WRITE   
$20
TO __stage00_output
```

**OUTPUT**

```
READ    
$20
FROM __stage00_output
AGGREGATE   
$10 := SUM_OF_COUNTS($20)
WRITE   
$10
TO __stage01_output
```

Found few similar issues here on SO, but all of them were using joins in the UDF query.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

The function call here:

```
with test_data as (
    select CAST('2021-05-01' as timestamp) from_date, CAST('2021-05-31' as timestamp) to_date,
    union all select CAST('2021-06-01' as timestamp) from_date, CAST('2021-06-20' as timestamp) to_date    
)

select     
*,    
my_test_function(from_date, to_date) as date_diff   
from 
    test_data
```

Comment: Have you tried the same view that fails without the UDF function? that should help to narrow down the issue

Comment: Please post your query including usage of the function... hard to diagnose your issue otherwise.

Comment: Hi, added the function call into the post.

Comment: @Alvaro - yep, it works fine without the UDF call